# Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions, for an array of processes

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to run the code below but I keep getting the error "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array". I am trying to write a code that finds all processes with the name "Inventor", and kill the ones that don't have a visible window.

```
Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Inventor")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To p.Count
            If p().MainWindowTitle Is Nothing Then
                p().Kill()
                MessageBox.Show("Killed")
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("none")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have absolutely no idea how I can call each individual "Inventor" process in the "p" array, and I have looked all over the web. I feel like the answer should be very simple. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not using your index in your code. For example: `If p().MainWindowTitle Is Nothing Then ...` you are missing the `i` to let it know what index... It should be `If p(i).MainWindowTitle`... Also turn on: `OptionStrict` it's your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are using `p()` and not specifying which member of the array you want to access. Here is an alternative.

```
Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
    Dim killed As Integer
    For Each proc As Process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Inventor")
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle) Then
            proc.Kill()
            MessageBox.Show("Killed")
            killed += 1
        End If
    Next
    If killed = 0 Then MessageBox.Show("none")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I used your code and at first, it wasnt shutting down any of the empty processes and it kept returning "None". I just had to change "Nothing" to "".

Comment: @RBuntu  or `String.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle)`

Comment: @Plutonix Good point. I simply copied the `Is Nothing` from the original question. I'll update the answer to correct it.

Comment: yea, happens all the time esp with code not *directly* related to the question  (+1)